# VS2010: Start Action for Debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

I'm trying to change the start action for debugging in a VS2010 (C-)project to run a .bat file.

I found on MSDNA a [How to: Change the Start Action for Application Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/68c8335t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on how to do that. Unfortunately, I can't find the mentioned "start action", although I'm using VS2010 (no express version). I have - when choosing the "Local Windows Debugger" - a "Command" field I can edit. I tried to enter there the full path to my .bat file, but that doesn't work, because the "file is unrecognized or unsupported binary format".

Do you know a) why I don't have "start action", b) why the bat file in the "command" field won't run?

*Edit* This is what it looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just created "console application" in vs2010 and found "Start Action" in place. What kind of project do you have?

[image]

**edit:**

a) "Start Action" is available only for .net projects

b) may be there is a problem with your .bat file. I just created an empty cpp project and set simple .bat file as Command. Everything works as expected.

Here is my .bat file

```
@echo on
pause
```

Try to use simple .bat and post the result here

Comment: No, sorry - here it looks completely different. I think I'm using an empty C++ project. I just edited my post to add a picture of what the properties look like here.

Comment: I did as you said, created a simple .bat file with the code you provided (and tested it separately). When I run (i.e. Start Debugging) it says: "Unable to start program 'C:\...\simple.bat'. The specified file is an unrecognized or unsupported binary format. What did you enter in the field command? I just put the path to the .bat file. Is something wrong with that?

Comment: I entered "E:\temp\test.bat"  (without quotes)

Comment: Another way. Try to set command as "cmd.exe" and Command Arguments as "/C E:\Temp\test.bat" (without quotes). If full path to .bat contains spaces you should quote it e.g. /C "C:\program files\test.bat"